# fetch profile info from google plus in java error

Tags: java, oauth, google-plus

i am trying to authenticate and and fetch user's profile data  but i a getting below error,Please suggest.

```
// Generate the URL to which we will direct users
    String authorizeUrl = new GoogleAuthorizationRequestUrl(CLIENT_ID,
            CALLBACK_URL, SCOPE).build();
    System.out.println("Paste this url in your browser: " + authorizeUrl);

    // Wait for the authorization code
    System.out.println("Type the code you received here: ");
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String authorizationCode = in.readLine();

    // Exchange for an access and refresh token
    GoogleAuthorizationCodeGrant authRequest = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeGrant(
            TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET,
            authorizationCode, CALLBACK_URL);
    authRequest.useBasicAuthorization = false;

    AccessTokenResponse authResponse = authRequest.execute();
    String accessToken = authResponse.accessToken;

    GoogleAccessProtectedResource requestInitializer = new GoogleAccessProtectedResource(
            accessToken, TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET,
            authResponse.refreshToken);

        // Set up the main Google+ class
    Plus plus = new Plus(TRANSPORT, requestInitializer,JSON_FACTORY);

    // Make a request to access your profile and display it to console
    Person profile = plus.people.get("me").execute();
    System.out.println("ID: " + profile.getId());
    System.out.println("Name: " + profile.getDisplayName());
    System.out.println("Image URL: " + profile.getImage().getUrl());
    System.out.println("Profile URL: " + profile.getUrl());
```

error is:-

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access field com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.method from class com.google.api.client.googleapis.MethodOverride
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.MethodOverride.overrideThisMethod(MethodOverride.java:99)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.MethodOverride.intercept(MethodOverride.java:87)
    at com.google.api.services.plus.ApiClient.buildHttpRequest(ApiClient.java:251)
    at com.google.api.services.plus.Plus$RemoteRequest.execute(Plus.java:1055)
    at com.google.api.services.plus.Plus$People$Get.executeUnparsed(Plus.java:991)
    at com.google.api.services.plus.Plus$People$Get.execute(Plus.java:976)
    at com.googleplus.test.TestAuth2.main(TestAuth2.java:64)

Comment: It might not be relevant to this specific problem but you're using  `OAuth 2.0 draft 10` which is [*deprecated*](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/OAuth2Draft10)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use the code from [this starter project](https://code.google.com/p/google-plus-java-starter/)?